# Argument is not parsed in \label{}

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I tried to create an auto-labeling function which is not working, I was able to break down the problem to the following line:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\label{fooref:#1}}
```

It looks like latex is not parsing #1 as an argument:
When I use `\foo{picture}` there is a link called `fooref:#1` instead of `fooref:picture`

Comment: Using your command with `\foo{stuff}` I see `fooref:stuff` in the `.aux` file, regardless whether I use packages that change the `\label` macro or do not use them. Please provide a compilable document that shows this issue. And [tag:label] is not meant for the `\label` macro ;-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I assume you’re using pdfLaTeX at present. Are you open to using LuaLaTeX?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which sets up two user macros: `\mylab` and `\myref`. The default prefix string for labels created via a `\mylabel` call is set to "fooref". This prefix can be overridden by providing an optional argument to `\mylab` and `\myref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mylab}[2][fooref]{\label{#1:#2}}
\newcommand{\myref}[2][fooref]{\ref{#1:#2}}

\begin{document}
\section{hello} \mylab{stuff} % label string is 'fooref:stuff'

\setcounter{equation}{7} % just for this example
\begin{equation} \mylab[zzz_ref]{euler} % label string is 'zzz_ref:euler'
   e^{i\pi}-1=0
\end{equation}

A cross-reference to section \myref{stuff}.

A cross-reference to equation \myref[zzz_ref]{euler}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see a lot of Black Lua Magic here, but is this really necessary? `\foo{stuff}` should write the label name `fooref:stuff` to the `.aux` file since it uses `\protected@write`, so `#1` in `\foo` will be expanded?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Thanks for this. The `\luastringN` macro does *not* expand its argument; that's what the `N` stands for... This makes it possible to users to employ `_` (underscore) and other TeX-special characters in the arguments of `\mylabel` -- and ultimately in the arguments of `\label`, `\ref`, `\eqref`, `\cref`, etc.

Comment: If I replace the definition of `\mylab` with `\newcommand{\mylab}[2][fooref]{\label{#1:#2}}` I get identical `.aux` files (and identical PDF files).

Comment: @egreg -- I've edited my answer to incorporate your suggestion/observation. The code is much simpler now!! :-)

Comment: @Mico: My point was, that the Black Lua Magic shouldn't be necessary at all ... ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Please see the now much simpler answer, courtesy of egreg. 

Comment: @Mico: I've seen the edit already. What is really different to the O.P. code of `\foo`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I suppose that the answer, in its newly-simplified form, is not all that different from the OP’s code...

Comment: @Mico: Yes... the question is unclear (and already closed)